Collections of distinct subsets of an interval (existence)
Question: does there exist an uncountable family of distinct subsets of $[-1, 1]$, denoted by $(U_j)_{j \in [-1, 1]}$, with the following properties? Throughout, $\mu$ is just the Lebesgue measure.
Property 1: for each $j \in [-1, 1]$, $$0 < \mu(U_j). \tag{1}$$
Property 2: for any $k \in (0, 1]$ and any non-empty $I \subseteq [-k, k]$,
$$\ \ \mu\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i \cap \bigcap_{j \in [-k, k]\backslash I} U^\mathsf{c}_j \right) = 0. \tag{2}$$
Thoughts: this would be easy if e.g. we only required Property 2 to hold for $k =1$.  For then $U_x = \{y: \frac{1}{2}(x - 1)  \leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}(x +1)\}$, $x \in [-1, 1]$ would be one such collection. But how to handle the general case?

You said the $U_j$ are supposed to be subsets of $[-1,1]$ but this doesn't make sense given your property 1 beyond being not of measure 0. Is this a typo?

@PeteCaradonna yes, yes, you're right, Property 1 just says that they all have positive measures. Edited it.
